# How to find the coefficients of the second eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus

I have a $2\times 2$ real symmetric matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
A & C \\
C & B 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and I know that the eigenvalues are:
$$\lambda_{\pm} = \frac{1}{2}(A+B)\pm \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(A-B)^{2}+C^{2}}$$
Define $x$ so that:
$\lambda_{\pm} = e^{\pm x}$. I know its first eigenvector, associated to $\lambda_{+}$. It is given by:
$$v = \cos \theta v_{1}+ \sin\theta v_{2}$$
where $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ form a basis for this two-dimensional space and the constant $\theta$ is defined by:
$$\tan\theta = \frac{C}{e^{x}-A}.$$
Here is my problem. If I want to find an (orthogonal) eigenvector of the matrix associated to $\lambda_{-}$, I would simply say it is given by:
$$w = \cos \Delta v_{1} + \sin\Delta v_{2}$$
where now:
$$\tan\Delta = \frac{C}{e^{-x}-A}$$
However, the result is supposed to be:
$$w = -\sin\theta v_{1} + \cos\theta v_{2}.$$

Why is that? I am trying to prove that the change $x \to -x$ implies $\cos\theta \to -\sin\theta$, but I really cannot prove it. Any help is useful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your $x$ doesn't exist unless $4AB-C^2=4$, which you obtain from the equality $\lambda_-=\frac1{\lambda_+}$. This just doesn't occur in general.

If instead of using your $e^{\pm x}$ you use $\lambda_{\pm}$, it is easy to check that
$$
\frac C{\lambda_--A}=-\Big(\frac{C}{\lambda_+-A}\Big)^{-1}, 
$$
which is precisely the relation $\tan\theta=-\frac1{\tan\Delta}$ which guarantees orthogonality.

As for

> However, the result is supposed to be:

the easier way to write a vector orthogonal to $$s\,v_1+t\,v_2,$$ if $v_1\perp v_2$, is $$-t\,v_1+s\,v_2.$$